# Getting value of input field and append to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get the value of my input appended to the DOM.
Not sure why I am not getting the value of my input box. I keep getting [object HTMLInputElement]... any help would be appreciate it. I tried couple of methods, but still not getting any results.

```js
// 'use strict';

var button;
var list = document.getElementById("greatList");
//var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
//console.log(item);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init(){
  button = document.getElementById('addButton');
 

 document.querySelector('#addButton').addEventListener('click', addField);
 //button.addEventListener('click', getItem)

}

function addField(){
 var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
 var newField = document.createElement('li');
 newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addItems));
 newField.classList.add('singleLine');
 list.appendChild(newField);
 console.log("working");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="list">
  <h2>List: </h2>
  <section class="top">

   <input type="text" value="input" id="addItems">
   <button type="submit" id="addButton" onclick="addField()">Add</button>
   <button>Get Random</button>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section class="result">
   <ul id="greatList">
    <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [bin](http://jsbin.com/qetonerito/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You want `newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));` Not `addItems` which is adding your id'ed input element.

Comment: thanks rgthree that worked... any idea why is it appending twice?

Comment: Yup. You have both an `onclick` attribute calling `addField()` _and_ an `addEventListener` in your `init` method. So, it's calling `addField` twice for each click. Remove the `onclick` attribute :)

Comment: awesome, man, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `addItems` instead of `item` in `document.createTextNode`

`addItems` is `id` of the element hence JS parser will append `<input type="text" value="input" id="addItems">` element.

> [*element IDs are global variables*](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html)

```js
var list = document.getElementById("greatList");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  document.querySelector('#addButton').addEventListener('click', addField);
}

function addField() {
  console.log(addItems);
  var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
  var newField = document.createElement('li');
  newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  newField.classList.add('singleLine');
  list.appendChild(newField);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <h2>List: </h2>
    <section class="top">

      <input type="text" value="input" id="addItems">
      <button type="submit" id="addButton">Add</button>
      <button>Get Random</button>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section class="result">
      <ul id="greatList">
        <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Avoid binding `inline-events`(You have `addEventListener` as well as `inline-click-event`) so it will invoke function twice..